# Get all possible outcomes of adding values into list

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list that I'd like to iterate through by adding values to each element and generating all possible outcomes of the said list with an upper bound on sum of list

For example I have a list [1, 1, 1, 1] and my upper bound is 6 for sum of list and a maximum upper bound of per element of 3.
I'd like to retrieve the possible outcomes

For 3s: [3, 1, 1, 1] --- [1, 3, 1, 1] --- [1, 1, 3, 1] --- [1, 1, 1, 3]

For 2s: [2, 2, 1, 1] --- [2, 1, 2, 1] --- [2, 1, 1, 2] --- [1, 2, 2, 1] --- [1, 1, 2, 2] --- [1, 2, 1, 2]

Currently my code is

```
# upper bound of 7 (sum)
# per element highest of 4
arr = [1, 1, 1, 1]
for i in range(1, 4):
    for idx, ele in enumerate(arr):
        arr[idx]+=i
        if sum(arr) == 7:
            print(arr)
        arr = [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I get `[4, 1, 1, 1] -- [1, 4, 1, 1] -- [1, 1, 4, 1] -- [1, 1, 1, 4]`. However, I am not very sure how to proceed with getting the other possibilities of generating a list of possibilities to obtain the sum of 7
i.e. [3, 2, 1, 1] -- [2, 2, 2, 1] and so on..

Could I get some hints on how do I do this?

Comment: It seems backtracking is the good candidate here.  See https://brilliant.org/wiki/recursive-backtracking/ .  And it does not have to be recursive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure i understand correctly.

if you want all lists of length `M` that add up to `SUM` (where `0` is not allowed as entry in the list) you could do this:

```
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations, partitions

SUM = 6
M = 4  # length of list

def dict_to_list(dct, m):
    ret = [0] * m
    j = 0
    for k, v in dct.items():
        ret[j:j + v] = [k] * v
        j += v
    return ret

for dct in partitions(SUM, m=M):
    if sum(dct.values()) != M:
        continue
    lst = dict_to_list(dct, M)
    for part in multiset_permutations(lst):
        print(part)
```

it outputs:

```
[1, 1, 1, 3]
[1, 1, 3, 1]
[1, 3, 1, 1]
[3, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 2, 1]
[2, 1, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 1, 1]
```

you need [`sympy`](https://www.sympy.org/) for this to work.

the algorithm starts by iterating over the [`partitions`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/iterables.html#partitions) of `SUM` (where i exclude partitions with more than `M` summands):

```
list(p.copy() for p in partitions(SUM, m=M))
# [{6: 1}, {5: 1, 1: 1}, {4: 1, 2: 1}, {4: 1, 1: 2}, {3: 2},
#  {3: 1, 2: 1, 1: 1}, {3: 1, 1: 3}, {2: 3}, {2: 2, 1: 2}]
```

this means: `6 = 1*6`, `5 = 5*1 + 1*1`, ..., `6 = 2*2 + 1*2`. from those i exclude the partitions that with less than `M` non-zero summands (`sum(dct.values()) != M`). the ones that pass the test are converted into lists with the `M` summands stated explicitly (`dict_to_list` does that):

```
{3: 1, 1: 3} -> [3, 1, 1, 1]
{2: 2, 1: 2} -> [2, 2, 1, 1]
```

then i call [`multiset_permutations`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/iterables.html#sympy.utilities.iterables.multiset_permutations) in order to get all the distinct permutations. as there may be duplicates in the list regular [`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) would do too much work and return too many results.

---

**update:** i just realized that the [`elements`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.elements) method of [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) could neatly replace my `dict_to_list` function from above. the whole code would then be:

```
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations, partitions
from collections import Counter

SUM = 6
M = 4  # length of list

for dct in partitions(SUM, m=M):
    if sum(dct.values()) != M:
        continue
    elements = Counter(dct).elements()
    for part in multiset_permutations(elements):
        print(part)
```

Comment: this was exactly what I wanted to do, if you do not mind, could you give a brief explanation of what it is for starters so I can look more into it on my own? Thanks!

Comment: @JonK added some explanation. hope that makes it a bit clearer...

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily accomplished with some recursion since you want to find all possible arrays that meet your criteria.

```
res_list = []
def find(arr):
    if res_list.count(arr):
        return
    for idx in range(0, len(arr)):
        for i in range(0, 4):
            if sum(arr) + i < 7:
                arr[idx] += i
                res_list.insert(arr)
                find(arr)

arr_orig = [1, 1, 1, 1]
find(arr_orig)
for res in res_list:
    print(res_list)
```

(sorry if some of my python syntax is a bit off, I dont usually code in python)